# ;Java - Sort a CSV file by date and time

Tags: java, file, csv, sorting

I have a problem while I try to sort my CSV file.
I need to get the 10 max frequency from a one time time period.
Like, every scan from the time 10:43:12 and to write them in one line.

To write them I have no problem, my problem is when i try to separate the time period and to calculate each time alone.

```
    public static void writeFile(String csvFile, String newCsv) {

    //Delimiter used in CSV file
    String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
    String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
    //CSV file header
    String FILE_HEADER = "Time, ID, Lat, Lon, Alt, SSID1, MAC1, Frequncy1, Signal1,"
            + " SSID2, MAC2, Frequncy2, Signal2,"
            + " SSID3, MAC3, Frequncy3, Signal3,"
            + " SSID4, MAC4, Frequncy4, Signal4,"
            + " SSID5, MAC5, Frequncy5, Signal5,"
            + " SSID6, MAC6, Frequncy6, Signal6,"
            + " SSID7, MAC7, Frequncy7, Signal7,"
            + " SSID8, MAC8, Frequncy8, Signal8,"
            + " SSID9, MAC9, Frequncy9, Signal9,"
            + " SSID10, MAC10, Frequncy10, Signal10";
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    int t=0;

    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(newCsv);
        //Write the CSV file header
        fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());
        //Add a new line separator after the header
        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
            String mod=returnMod(csvFile);
            br.readLine(); // this will read the first line
            br.readLine();// this will read the second line
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator(There is 11 column)
                String[] column = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                fileWriter.append(column[3]);//time
                String s=column[3];
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(mod);//model
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(column[6]);//lat
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(column[7]);//lon
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(column[8]);//alt
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(column[1]);//wifi
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(column[0]);//MAC
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(column[4]);//frq
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(column[5]);//signal
                fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);



            }
        } 

        System.out.println("CSV file was created successfully !!!");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code just write all the data to a new file, I was trying to change it to fit my needs, but I could not do it

Comment: why the tag `url-rewriting`?

Comment: my bad.. a miss click

Comment: is the input file sorted by time?

Comment: @AxelH That's what I have done, I took all the files and merge it to one..now I have a one file but don't know how to compere just the date-time in each line

Comment: @AxelH I'm kinda new to this, do u have any recommended API?

Comment: @MauricePerry yap

Comment: what is the format of the frequency? is it an integer?

Comment: @YAK, my bad! (was commenting during the reading) well if you have done it properly, just read each line and check the last date with the current to see if this is the same date (note that your title is way off). Or start using `Stream` to group it I guess (not my best domain unfortunatly). And for any API, google it... SO is not meant for that.

Comment: @MauricePerry yes

Comment: @AxelH I don't know hot to do the compering between the line..
every time the code read 1 line and if I skip all the another data will be lost

Comment: What about ... using a variable to store the last values ? This is a simple implementation that you should be able to do yourself (there is more efficient way to do it... but that's a simple solution)

Comment: @AxelH was trying to do that, but every time the code reading the new line so when i compere them its like i will compere the same String..
didn't found a way to store the last String

Comment: What about ID, Lat, Lon, Alt? they seem to vary, event when the time is the same.

Comment: @MauricePerry I just need to sort it by time...hmm like, to get the 10 most powerful frq of a certain time..
so I just need a way to compere lines and get all of the line from a same time and find the 10 max

Comment: @MauricePerry to compere the frq is not a problem

Comment: @YAK no, it's not, but which ones will be written to the output file?

Comment: @MauricePerry the line should look like this:
Time, ID, Lat, Lon, Alt, SSID#, MAC#, Frequncy#, Signal#.....
When 1<=#<=10

Comment: @MauricePerry 10/30/2017 18:10,model=LG-H815,32.10483761,35.20963138,684,Ariel_University,1c:b9:c4:16:05:38,1,-78,Ariel_University,1c:b9:c4:15:44:58,11,-83,EVE,d8:fe:e3:03:4f:a9,1,-85

Comment: @MauricePerry somthing like that haha..

Comment: @MauricePerry https://ibb.co/fdjYxb

Comment: By the way, a tip: [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/csv/) to handle reading and writing CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would declare a class to hold the info:

```
public static class Info {
    public final String time;
    public final int frq;
    public final String mod;
    public final String lat;
    public final String lon;
    public final String alt;
    public final String wifi;
    public final String mac;
    public final String signal;

    public Info(String[] column, String mod) {
        time = column[3];
        this.mod = mod;
        lat = column[6];
        lon = column[7];
        alt = column[8];
        wifi = column[1];
        mac = column[0];
        frq = Integer.parseInt(column[4]);
        signal = column[5];
    }
}
```

And an array of Info to store the 10 infos with max frequency. The loop becomes:

```
    Info[] max = new Info[10];
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // use comma as separator(There is 11 column)
        String[] column = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        Info info = new Info(column, mod);
        if (count > 0 && !max[0].time.equals(info.time)) {
            printPeriod(max, count, fileWriter);
            count = 0;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count && max[i].frq > info.frq) {
            ++i;
        }
        while (i < count) {
            Info pred = max[i];
            max[i] = info;
            info = pred;
            ++i;
        }
        if (count < max.length) {
            max[count++] = info;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        printPeriod(max, count, fileWriter);
    }
```

And here's the printPeriod method:

```
private static void printPeriod(Info[] max, int count, Writer fileWriter) {
    fileWriter.append(max[0].time);
    fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
    fileWriter.append(max[0].mod);
    fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
    fileWriter.append(max[0].lat);
    fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
    fileWriter.append(max[0].lon);
    fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
    fileWriter.append(max[0].alt);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
        fileWriter.append(max[i].wifi);
        fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
        fileWriter.append(max[i].mac);
        fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
        fileWriter.append(Integer.toString(max[i].frq));
        fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
        fileWriter.append(max[i].signal);
    }
    fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
}
```

Comment: @YAK note that for lat, lon, alt, I have used the first info, that is the one with the highest frequency

Comment: ya that was the idea :)
but if I want to sort them now by the signal (and it's a negative val)
what do I need to change here?

Comment: like if we have -90 and -20, the -90 is stronger

Comment: ohhh nvm I found it!